# How to calculate fragmentation?

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded, fragmentation

Imagine you have some memory containing a bunch of bytes:

```
++++ ++-- ---+ +++-
-++- ++++ ++++ ----
---- ++++ +
```

Let us say `+` means allocated and `-` means free.

I'm searching for the **formula** of how to calculate the **percentage of fragmentation**.

**Background**

I'm implementing a tiny dynamic memory management for an embedded device with static memory. My goal is to have something I can use for storing small amounts of data. Mostly incoming packets over a wireless connection, at about 128 Bytes each.

Comment: Ahh...I see. It depends on how big my allocation blocks are.

Comment: If all your blocks are about the same size, and your memory is static and your system too small to use caching for memory access, fragmentation may not really matter - you have to keep track of which slots are free and which aren't, but jumping around in access shouldn't cost you much.  That's in contrast to an electromechanical disk drive where you have to move the heads when you skip around, or perhaps a system of slow DRAM and chache where skipping around would cause a lot of cache misses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As R. says, it depends exactly what you mean by "percentage of fragmentation" - but one simple formula you could use would be:

```
(free - freemax)
----------------   x 100%    (or 100% for free=0)
    free
```

where

```
free     = total number of bytes free
freemax  = size of largest free block
```

That way, if all memory is in one big block, the fragmentation is 0%, and if memory is all carved up into hundreds of tiny blocks, it will be close to 100%.

Answer (score 7):

Calculate how many 128 bytes packets you could fit in the current memory layout.
Let be that number n.

Calculate how many 128 bytes packets you could fit in a memory layout with the same number of bytes allocated than the current one, but with no holes (that is, move all the + to the left for example).
Let be that number N.

Your "fragmentation ratio" would be alpha = n/N

Answer (score 4):

If your allocations are all roughly the same size, just split your memory up into `TOTAL/MAXSIZE` pieces each consisting of `MAXSIZE` bytes. Then fragmentation is irrelevant.

To answer your question in general, there is no magic number for "fragmentation". You have to evaluate the merits of different functions in reflecting how fragmented memory is. Here is one I would recommend, as a function of a size `n`:

```
fragmentation(n) = -log(n * number_of_free_slots_of_size_n / total_bytes_free)
```

Note that the `log` is just there to map things to a "0 to infinity" scale; you should not actually evaluate that in practice. Instead you might simply evaluate:

```
freespace_quality(n) = n * number_of_free_slots_of_size_n / total_bytes_free
```

with `1.0` being ideal (able to allocate the maximum possible number of objects of size `n`) and `0.0` being very bad (unable to allocate any).

Answer (score 0):

If you had [++++++-----++++--++-++++++++--------+++++] and you wanted to measure the fragmentation of the free space (or any other allocation)
You could measure the average contiguous block size
Total blocks / Count of contiguous blocks.

In this case it would be
4/(5 + 2 + 1 + 8) / 4 = 4

Answer (score 0):

Based on [R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587063/794075), I came up with the following way of computing fragmentation as a single percentage number:

[image: Fragmentation = 1 - 1/n * sum with i=1..n of FreeSlots(i)/IdealFreeSlots(i)]

Where:

- `n` is the total number of free blocks
- `FreeSlots(i)` means how many `i`-sized slots you can fit in the available free memory space
- `IdealFreeSlots(i)` means how many `i`-sized slots would fit in a perfectly unfragmented memory of size `n`. This is a simple calculation: `IdealFreeSlots(i) = floor(n / i)`.

---

##### How I came up with this formula:

I was thinking about how I could combine all the `freespace_quality(i)` values to get a single fragmentation percentage, but I wasn't very happy with the result of this function. Even in an ideal scenario, you could have `freespace_quality(i) != 1` if the free space size `n` is not divisible by `i`. For example, if `n=10` and `i=3`, `freespace_quality(3) = 9/10 = 0.9`.

So, I created a derived function `freespace_relative_quality(i)` which looks like this:

[image: freespace_relative_quality(i) = freespace_quality(i) / ideal_freespace_quality(i)]

This would always have the output `1` in the ideal "perfectly unfragmented" scenario.

After doing the math:

[image]

All that's left to do now to get to the final fragmentation formula is to calculate the average freespace quality for all values of `i` (from `1` to `n`), and then invert the range by doing `1 - the average quality` so that 0 means completely unfragmented (maximum quality) and 1 means most fragmented (minimum quality).